# Serving concurrent requests with Apache2 + PHP 7.0 FPM works with curl but not Firefox or Chromium

Tags: php, apache, apache2, fastcgi

My machine is running Debian 9 stretch with Apache 2.4.25 and PHP 7.0 FPM via proxy_fcgi_module to serve php files.

This is my configuration for php-fpm withing Apache:

```
<IfModule !mod_php7.c>
<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
<IfModule setenvif_module>
SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml)$">
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
    # Deny access to raw php sources by default
    # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
    # only in specific virtual host or directory
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
# Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
<FilesMatch "^\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml|ps)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

This was working fine for months but now I stumbled upon the following issue with these two php scripts:

First script:

```
<?php
sleep(30);
echo "test 1\n";
?>
```

Second script:

```
<?php
echo "test 2\n";
?>
```

I open the URL of the first script via Firefox and directly after that I open the URL of the seconds script within a second tab.

**What happens:**
The second script waits and loads after the first one has finished loading.

**What I was expecting to happen:**
The second tab should load instantly.

I also noticed something interesting: If I call these two script via curl the seconds one loads instantly.

I have tested the latest versions of Firefox (58.0.1), Chromium (64.0.3282.119) and curl (7.58.0).

**UPDATE:**

This seems to be related to HTTP2. If I disable HTTP2 in Firefox via about:config with:

```
network.http.spdy.enabled.http2 = false
```

it works.

Comment: Did you try that with another browser yet? I remember issues where Firefox blocked parallel requests to the same url when one request is running yet.

Comment: I now also tried the following:

- GNOME's web browser: works as expected
- Microsoft Edge: doesn't work, seconds script waits for the first one
- Firefox with second script loading in private mode: works as expected

I know about PHP's session locking but I don't use any. At the moment I am wondering if this could be related to HTTP2 which tries to use one TCP connection?!